# Hide and Show Textview with button click in Dialog fragment

Tags: visibility, android-dialogfragment

I am new to programming and i hope someone can help provide me a simple code

I have a dialog fragment with a textview and a button.
It loaded with both visible.
when I click on the button, I need to hide the textview.
when I click it again, I need the textview to be shown.

I tried textview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

The textview still stays there, i think i am missing a refresh method???

Thanks

```
btnclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi, Use if else loop it will solve this issue for example refer this code

```
boolean s=true;
btnclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
if(s) {
textview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
s=false;
}
else {
textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
s=true;
}
} });
```